# Recursively list dependencies / references of a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, hierarchy, impdp

I'm trying to import a subset of our production dump with `impdp` for our local development database running on Oracle XE.

To find out what other objects I have to import for a particular stored procedure to work, I'm recursively querying `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` with the following example from [Recursively list concents of Oracle's DBA_DEPENDENCIES view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797922/recursively-list-concents-of-oracles-dba-dependencies-view):

```
SELECT TYPE, OWNER, NAME,
       REFERENCED_TYPE, REFERENCED_OWNER, REFERENCED_NAME 
FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES 
START WITH NAME='EXAMPLE_PROCEDURE' AND OWNER='EXAMPLE_OWNER' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
  PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = NAME;
```

Unfortunetly, while this does show me tables needed somehow by the procedure, it doesn't include the table's triggers and the trigger's dependencies, only returning me a chain like this:

`PROCEDURE -> FUNCTION -> TABLE [missing: -> TRIGGER -> FUNCTION -> TABLE -> ...]`

This seems to be the case because `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` does include triggers and their referenced objects, but does not include triggers as referenced objects from a table. So I rewrote the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TYPE, OWNER, NAME,
    REFERENCED_TYPE, REFERENCED_OWNER, REFERENCED_NAME 
  FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES
  UNION
  SELECT BASE_OBJECT_TYPE as TYPE, OWNER, TABLE_NAME as NAME,
    'TRIGGER' as REFERENCED_TYPE, TABLE_OWNER as REFERENCED_OWNER, TRIGGER_NAME as REFERENCED_NAME
  FROM DBA_TRIGGERS
)
START WITH NAME='EXAMPLE_PROCEDURE' AND OWNER='EXAMPLE_OWNER' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
  PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = NAME;
```

Now I get the referenced triggers of referenced tables in the result set, but not the references of the referenced triggers, with a chain looking like this:

`PROCEDURE -> FUNCTION -> TABLE -> TRIGGER [missing: -> FUNCTION -> TABLE -> ...]`

When querying `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` manually for referenced triggers, I can see that they actually have references.

Why aren't they returned with the `CONNECT BY` query, and how would I need to rewrite the query to include those too?

Comment: I created a fiddle at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37730250365ca05e0e8e22294474b121 but I'm unable to create even the simplest procedure without compilation errors (never used Oracle before). Can you extend on that and create a procedure that references child and post back the url? If the setup does not illustrate the problem, can you also extend it so it does?